# check if network drive exists and mount it otherwise check until it's available

Tags: vbscript, wait, drive

I need help creating a VBScript to do the following:

Launch a service called "NAS PM service"

```
net start "NAS PM service"
```

then check if \192.168.1.1\drive1 exists

```
IF EXIST \192.168.1.1\drive1
```

If it does, map it to a drive specifying a login/pass:

```
net use M: \192.168.1.1\Disk_1 password /USER:admin
```

If it does not exist yet, wait 10 seconds before attempting to map it again (until success).

I know more or less how to do this as a batch file using `ping` to wait but I'd rather use a small and clean VBScript without `ping`.

Answer (score 1):

Enable error handling during the connection attempts and continue as long as you keep getting an error:

```
Set net = CreateObject("WScript.Network")

On Error Resume Next
Do
  Err.Clear
  net.MapNetworkDrive "M:", "\\192.168.1.1\Disk_1", False, "admin", "password"
  If Err Then WScript.Sleep 10000
Loop While Err
On Error Goto 0

WScript.Echo "Drive connected."
```

It might be a good idea to limit the maximum number of connection attempts, though, otherwise the script will loop forever if the remote share never goes online.

The service can be started via WMI like this:

```
Set wmi = GetObject("winmgmts://./root/cimv2")

qry = "SELECT * FROM Win32_Service WHERE Name='NAS PM service' AND State='Stopped'"
For Each svc In wmi.ExecQuery(qry)
  svc.StartService
Next
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I have a 2 more questions if you have a little time: Q1. Is the condition in your script:: On Error Resume Next Do <snip> Loop While Err On Error Goto 0 the equivalent to: Dim k (at the top of the script) <snip> Do On Error Resume Next <snip> k=k+1 Loop Until Err.Number=0 ? Q2. Is there a difference between doing your method to load the service via WMI versus just this: objShell.Run ("net start ""NAS PM service"""), 0, False ?

Comment: @TheShadowRunner A1: No, the code snippets are not equivalent. The body of a loop is not a different scope in VBScript, so your second example never disables error handling. A2: Both will work, but WMI is the cleaner approach.